# Accessing custom variables from a .phtml in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a file (js.phtml) where my code executes. I need to access some user data. When I error_log($this) in js.phtml, it displays, "Mage_Core_Block_Template" - which is confusing to me. I would expect that to be the parent class, not the value of the class getting passed to my .phtml file.

So, how do I supply the .phtml file with custom objects or methods? I'm super new to Magento and I've just been dropped into a task, so I apologize for possibly using incorrect terminology.

Edit:
My full file path is:

- /app/design/frontend//default/template/customer/welcome/js.phtml

There is also a full module dir here:

- /app/code/local//Customer/

Edit: 
I need access to the users country and userid. It's ok if country is null.

Edit:
I've been doing additional research, it looks like I can do something like this: 
[Current user in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416553/current-user-in-magento)

But I haven't tried it in code yet ....

Edit: Figured it out:

```
error_log(print_r(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEntityId(), true));
error_log(print_r(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getCountry(), true));
```

Comment: what objects/methods do you need to use?  Could you describe a little more what your js.phtml file is trying to accomplish?

Comment: Something wrong with your path. Path to default theme template folder is `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get customer ID:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
```

To get country - depends from which address. Here's an example of getting the country code from the default billing address:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountry();
```

Comment: Interesting, getDefaultBillingAddress(), instead of what I did. Cool, I'll have to dig into the possible difference.

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat new to Magento, but I think this should work.

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

That gets the customer object.  Then...

```
echo $customer->getAddresses();
```

That should get the country somewhere in the address.  As for userid...I don't see it on the documentation page..You could try

```
echo $customer->getAttributes();
```

And see what is in there.  The documentation page is at:

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Customer/Mage_Customer_Model_Customer.html

Comment: good edit.  This post should also be helpful http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22382/

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to edit your post. This is great info though. +1. I took the other as answer though as they beat you to it.

Comment: not a problem.  the other post was more efficient, I tend to ramble in my posts a bit. Appreciate the +1!