# How to get Magento customer ID

Tags: php, magento

Ugh how do I get the customer ID!!? These are all things I've tried! Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
//include_once "app/Mage.php";
require_once '/home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php';

//Mage::app("default");

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

if($customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId())->getData();
    print_r($customerData);
    echo $customerData->getId();
}

//$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
//$customerID = $customerData -> getId(); 

//$userinfo = $customerData->_origData; // fetch users info
$customerID=$customer -> getId(); 
//$customerID = $customerData->getEntityId();
//$customerID = $customerData[entity_id];
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try

```
 if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      echo $customerData->getId();
 }
```

See [Current user in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416553/current-user-in-magento)

Comment: It is not getting into the if statement at all! I AM logged in but I added an else statement echo "not logged in" and that is what is being printed.

Comment: Try changing the store id from admin to the correct customer's store id

Answer (score 17):

The fastest way is

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId()
```

Comment: this doesn't return the session id?

Answer (score 3):

The function `isLoggedIn` will only return a boolean as to if a customer is logged in and no other information.

The customer session does have to following functions:

1. `getCustomerId`: which will return the customer id
2. `getCustomer`: which will return the customer object.

Comment: It's not even getting past the logged in boolean when I AM logged in.

Comment: have you tried adding the following line after the Mage::app(); Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); though are you access the admin section or the front end?